# Postgres - escape double quotes inside escaped double quotes

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table named **summary** which has two columns, **id** which is **SERIAL** and **summary** which is an **array of json** elements.

To insert in this table, i have to follow this syntax:

```
insert into summary values (default, '{"{\"index\": -1, \"nivel\": -1, `\"title\": \"hello world\"`, \"children\": []}"}')
```

But if i want to escape double quotes inside title, for example:

```
insert into summary values (default, '{"{\"index\": -1, \"nivel\": -1, \"title\": \"hello \"world\"\", \"children\": []}"}')
```

It returns this error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 1: insert into summary values (default, '{"{\"index\": -1, \"ni...
                                             ^
DETAIL:  Token "world" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: {"index": -1, "nivel": -1, "title": "hello "world...
```

How can i escape that properly?

Comment: can you remove default and try like this `insert into summary(symmary_col) values ( '{"{\"index\": -1, \"nivel\": -1, `\"title\": \"hello world\"`, \"children\": []}"}')`. You dont have to specify default, postgres will take care of it.

Comment: Why `json[]` and not `json` (or better: `jsonb`) and use a "json array"`?

Comment: consider instead inserting a postgres array and let postgres deal with storing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double escape the double quotes by putting an escaped backslash in front:

```json
\"hello \\\"world\\\"\"
```